# Python script in toolbox

Tags: qgis, python, python-toolbox, toolbox

I have a python script that clean my symbology for the selected layer, from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438048/remove-empty-categories-from-toc):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
layer = iface.activeLayer() # get the active layer
renderer = layer.renderer().clone() # get layer renderer
exp = QgsExpression(renderer.classAttribute()) # get the category expression
field_map = []
# evaluate the expression for each feature and store results in a list
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    exp_context = QgsExpressionContext()
    exp_context.setFeature(feature)
    field_map.append(exp.evaluate(exp_context))
    
categories = renderer.categories()
for cat in categories.copy():
    if not field_map.count(cat.value()): # if there's no feature with this value
        renderer.deleteCategory(renderer.categoryIndexForValue(cat.value())) # remove the category
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

But it doesn't appear in the toolbox. How should I modified it, so that it appears in the toolbox, and when I open it, I need to select on which layer to run it?

[EDIT]
OK, I tied to follow the comment of @Louis Cottereau, but I have an error on line 51. Can anyone help me?

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'clean_toc'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Clean TOC')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Drosera')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'drosera'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Permet de nettoyer la liste des valeurs dans la table")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        layer = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        renderer = layer.renderer().clone() # get layer renderer
        exp = QgsExpression(renderer.classAttribute()) # get the category expression
        field_map = []
        # evaluate the expression for each feature and store results in a list
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            exp_context = QgsExpressionContext()
            exp_context.setFeature(feature)
            field_map.append(exp.evaluate(exp_context))
    
        categories = renderer.categories()
        for cat in categories.copy():
            if not field_map.count(cat.value()): # if there's no feature with this value
                renderer.deleteCategory(renderer.categoryIndexForValue(cat.value())) # remove the category
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

[EDIT2]:
As a respond to @RainForest, it is not a UI form problem, but a python problem.
[image]

Comment: Checkout the documentation of how to create a Processing algorithms as Python scripts: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html . Here you basically only need to setup one `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer` as input of algorithm and put your script code in `processAlgorithm` function and just handle the input

Comment: " error on line 51." What is the error?

Comment: It says: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\stoant\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\test.py", line 51, in processAlgorithm
renderer = layer.renderer().clone() # get layer renderer
AttributeError: 'QgsProcessingFeatureSource' object has no attribute 'renderer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually get the layer from the `context` argument of the function with `QgsProcessingContext.getMapLayer(identifier) -> QgsMapLayer` ([source](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingContext.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingContext.getMapLayer))

I have also changed `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` to `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer` since you don't need the added benefits and parameters of `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` so its simpler.

You were also missing some imports and a return value even if it is empty in your case.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
                       QgsExpression,
                       QgsExpressionContext)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'clean_toc'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Clean TOC')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Drosera')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'drosera'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Permet de nettoyer la liste des valeurs dans la table")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # getting the layer from the QgsProcessingContext
        # old: (correct solution but non standard)
        # layer = context.getMapLayer(parameters[self.INPUT]) 
        # new: 
        layer = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

        renderer = layer.renderer().clone() # get layer renderer
        exp = QgsExpression(renderer.classAttribute()) # get the category expression
        field_map = []
        # evaluate the expression for each feature and store results in a list
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            exp_context = QgsExpressionContext()
            exp_context.setFeature(feature)
            field_map.append(exp.evaluate(exp_context))
    
        categories = renderer.categories()
        for cat in categories.copy():
            if not field_map.count(cat.value()): # if there's no feature with this value
                renderer.deleteCategory(renderer.categoryIndexForValue(cat.value())) # remove the category
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        
        return {}
```

EDIT:

```py
layer = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
```

This is better in that this is the more logic and standard/homogeneous way of extracting parameters from all `QgsProcessingParameter` inside the `processAlgorithm` function

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Is it normal on QGIS 3.22 that if the value for categorized is a 'int' or a 'real', it doesn't work? I need to add a 'to_string' and it works?!?

Comment: I have the same version of qgis and I believe I tried it on a int field but not sure, I'll check tomorrow. It probably has to do with `exp.evaluate(exp_context))`. What the error you got if there was one?

Comment: I tried on int, float and string fields categorization and didn't any error and it worked. can you produce a reproducible case ?

Comment: You can find an exemple here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ROEnbG7UwZdxaMqouXMr8OkSDmzxinDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't really have an error, it is just that the symbology is empty after using the processing.

Comment: Hum with your file it doens't work but if I create the categorization just like you have it it works. I am not certain whats happening. It might be relevant to create a new question for the problem, this comments are getting crowded and it is not totaly relevant to the original question

Comment: I know... but it will be difficult to write a new question with such a problem. But anyway, thank you for everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139516/discussion-between-louis-cottereau-and-katagena).

Answer (score -2):

Processing give you access to the layer features data only, but not to the layer instance itself in project. So, you have to create your own little python plugin, not algorithm. Create ui form (run QtDesigner!) where you can select layer (it's QgsMapLayerComboBox element in QtDesigner) and put the code above to the action on some button press in the form.

Action button to open his form you can place in any toolbox.

Comment: No... it's not a UI form problem (see my edit above). It is a python problem.

Comment: Yes, it's python problem. Because in processing algorythm you use QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer class. It's not the same as  QgsMapLayer class, wich have "renderer" method. The main idea of processing architecture is ability to construct Models: get input layer, run some transformations, put result in output layer. Your task has to be solved via plugin, not processing.

Comment: But here it works? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438048/remove-empty-categories-from-toc, without needing a plugin?!?

Comment: Of course, you can run code from console without processing algorithm or plugin.

Comment: Actually it is really simple to access `QgsMapLayer` from `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`. Besides, accessing the renderer and the layer symbologies from a processing algorithm is perfectly fine in my opinion (there are some native qgis algorithms which do it like "native:categorizeusingstyle"). The only difference here is that the operation is done in place which is not the "standard" for processing algorithms but its fine for symbologies since its enterily cosmetic and thus reversible and reproductible from the data